# link color based on siblings links :visited

Tags: html, css

I have links

```
<a href="#one"></a>
<a href="#two"></a>
```

I am trying to make link #one black on **:visited** and #two blue. When visiting #two reverse should apply #one should be blue and #two should be black. I am trying to color the last visited link black and others to default. I tried

```
a {
 color:blue;
}
a:visited ~ a:not(:visited){
  color:red
}
```

I am trying to achieve this with just CSS without using JS.

Comment: Without Js you can't acheive this.

Comment: hello, what behavior would you want when both `#one` and `#two` are already `:visited`?

Comment: @ArnelleBalane I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
 color:blue;
}
a:visited{
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: I need the first one to become default color when second one is visited after visiting first one

Comment: Well the browser knows that the old link has been visited :)

Comment: Still,  the browser knows the link has been visited.

Comment: could a combination of :active an :visited be used to achieve this? and does it matter if the browser knows?

Comment: :active will be there till the mouse is clicked.